# Spark Streaming doesn't contain KafkaUtils

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I created a project in which I want to consume a kafka stream.
For that reason I need to use the KafkaUtils from spark streaming.
But when I try to use KafkaUtils, they cannot be resolved.

I added the spark-streaming_2.11-2.0.1.jar and tried to  import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.*;. But it can't be resolved either.

Can somebody tell me what I'm missing?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using

spark-streaming_2.11-2.0.1.jar

but I needed the

spark-streaming-kafka_2.10-1.6.2.jar

Nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add spark-streaming-kafka_2.11-2.0.1.jar before using KafkaUtils

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._` instead of  `import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.*` in Scala.